# React Native - Response Status Returned By The API Is Always Undefined In The Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await

Below is my code. I am calling a function from the child in the parent component which makes an API call, based on the response status I want to add some behavior to the child but the problem is that that status returned by the API call is always `undefined` in the child whereas I can `console.log` it in the parent and I see the expected status code.
Seems like the child is printing the status before the response is received but I believe I have async/await at the necessary places but ofcourse I could be wrong.

**The Parent Component:**

```
  const MemberHomeScreen = () => {

  const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState({});

  const handlePress = async lookingToPlay => {
    console.log("Inside Member Home Screen Looking to play", lookingToPlay);
    try {
      const changeMatchStatus = async () => {
      const response = await axios.put('https://c7971702c7e7.ngrok.io/match', {lookingToPlay});
      console.log("Here is the reponse for the update", response.status); // I can see this
      return response.status;
     }
      changeMatchStatus();
    } catch(error) {
      console.log("There has been an error.")
    }
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
        const userData = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get('https://c7971702c7e7.ngrok.io/profile');
        setUserProfile(response.data);
      }
      userData();
    } catch(error) {
      console.log("There has been an error.")
    }
    }, [])

  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      { userProfile && <UserMatchButton lookingToPlay={userProfile.lookingToPlay} changeMatchStatus={handlePress} /> }
    </View>
  )
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
const UserMatchButton = ({lookingToPlay, changeMatchStatus}) => {
const [matchStatus, setMatchStatus] = useState(lookingToPlay);

const handleLocalPress = async () => {
  const status = await changeMatchStatus(!matchStatus);
  console.log("status in child..............." + status); // always undefined

  setMatchStatus(!matchStatus)
  
}

return <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={() =>  handleLocalPress()}
    >
      <Text h3 style={styles.statusButton} >Play</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating a function inside the handlePress, why not call the API directly instead?

```
 const handlePress = async (lookingToPlay) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.put('https://c7971702c7e7.ngrok.io/match', {lookingToPlay});
      return response.status;
    } catch(error) {
      console.log("There has been an error.")
    }
  }
```

Also, seems like the API could be called in the child component since it's independent of the state in Parent.

Comment: I believe I have to write it that way otherwise async calls do not work in useEffect. As for directly calling the function I could do that but I like to keep all api calls in the parent.

Comment: why do you mean by `async calls do not work in useEffect`?

Comment: sorry I thought you were referring to the useEffect hook in the component. You are right I did not need to write it that way. No clue why I did that. I have updated it now (updated code above also) but I still have the same issue.

Comment: And I changed my code back to how it was so it will make sense to who ever reads this, they can see my original code and then your suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try making handlePress also async await ?

```
const handlePress = async (lookingToPlay) => {
```

Comment: For a moment I was like ahh that has to be it, how did I miss that but sadly it did not work  :-( Still undefined.